# Reduce the gap between two blocks in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a project and I got to a part where Im supposed to reduce the gap between the blocks to 3px. I have tried my best the last 2 days but i can not get the desired display.

This a screen capture of what have done:
[Screen Capture of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMLCt.jpg)

Im not able to run snippet when I paste my codes in this post so I will just give out the needed code for you to provide me your help.

```js
(function($) {
 var aux  = {
   // navigates left / right
   navigate : function( dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache ) {
    
    var scroll  = opts.scroll,
     factor  = 1,
     idxClicked = 0;
     
    if( cache.expanded ) {
     scroll  = 1; // scroll is always 1 in full mode
     factor  = 3; // the width of the expanded item will be 3 times bigger than 1 collapsed item 
     idxClicked = cache.idxClicked; // the index of the clicked item
    }
    
    // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
    if( dir === 1 ) {
     $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
      $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', ( cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).appendTo( $wrapper );
     });
    }
    else {
     var $first = $wrapper.children().eq(0);
     
     $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + ( cache.totalItems  - 1 - scroll ) + ')').each(function(i) {
      // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
      $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', - ( scroll - i + idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).insertBefore( $first );
     });
    }
    
    // animate the left of each item
    // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
    $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
     var $item = $(this);
     $item.stop().animate({
      left :  ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px' : '+=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px'
     }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
      if( ( dir === 1 && $item.position().left < - idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor ) || ( dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ( ( cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor ) ) ) {
       // remove the item that was cloned
       $item.remove();
      }      
      cache.isAnimating = false;
     });
    });
    
   },
   // opens an item (animation) -> opens all the others
   openItem : function( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache ) {
    cache.idxClicked = $item.index();
    // the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items) 
    cache.winpos  = aux.getWinPos( $item.position().left, cache );
    $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').not( $item ).hide();
    $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css( 'left', cache.itemW + 'px' ).stop().animate({
     width : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px',
     left : cache.itemW + 'px'
    }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
    .end()
    .stop()
    .animate({
     left : '0px'
    }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
     cache.isAnimating = false;
     cache.expanded  = true;
     
     aux.openItems( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache );
    });
      
   },
   // opens all the items
   openItems : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
    var openedIdx = $openedItem.index();
    
    $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
     var $item = $(this),
      idx  = $item.index();
     
     if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
      $item.css( 'left', - ( openedIdx - idx ) * ( cache.itemW * 3 ) + 'px' ).show().find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
       left : cache.itemW + 'px',
       width : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px'
      });
      
      // hide more link
      aux.toggleMore( $item, false );
     }
    });
   },
   // show / hide the item's more button
   toggleMore : function( $item, show ) {
    ( show ) ? $item.find('a.ca-more').show() : $item.find('a.ca-more').hide(); 
   },
   // close all the items
   // the current one is animated
   closeItems : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
    var openedIdx = $openedItem.index();
    
    $openedItem.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({
     width : '0px'
    }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
    .end()
    .stop()
    .animate({
     left : cache.itemW * ( cache.winpos - 1 ) + 'px'
    }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
     cache.isAnimating = false;
     cache.expanded  = false;
    });
    
    // show more link
    aux.toggleMore( $openedItem, true );
    
    $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
     var $item = $(this),
      idx  = $item.index();
     
     if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
      $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
       width : '0px'
      })
      .end()
      .css( 'left', ( ( cache.winpos - 1 ) - ( openedIdx - idx ) ) * cache.itemW + 'px' )
      .show();
      
      // show more link
      aux.toggleMore( $item, true );
     }
    });
   },
   // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
   // val is the left of the item
   getWinPos : function( val, cache ) {
    switch( val ) {
     case 0      : return 1; break;
     case cache.itemW   : return 2; break;
     case cache.itemW * 2  : return 3; break;
    }
   }
  },
  methods = {
   init   : function( options ) {
    
    if( this.length ) {
     
     var settings = {
      sliderSpeed  : 500,   // speed for the sliding animation
      sliderEasing : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the sliding animation
      itemSpeed  : 500,   // speed for the item animation (open / close)
      itemEasing  : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the item animation (open / close)
      scroll   : 1    // number of items to scroll at a time
     };
     
     return this.each(function() {
      
      // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
      if ( options ) {
       $.extend( settings, options );
      }
      
      var $el    = $(this),
       $wrapper  = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
       $items   = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
       cache   = {};
      
      // save the with of one item 
      cache.itemW   = $items.width();
      // save the number of total items
      cache.totalItems = $items.length;
      
      // add navigation buttons
      if( cache.totalItems > 3 ) 
       $el.prepend('<div class="ca-nav"><span class="ca-nav-prev">Previous</span><span class="ca-nav-next">Next</span></div>') 
      
      // control the scroll value
      if( settings.scroll < 1 )
       settings.scroll = 1;
      else if( settings.scroll > 3 )
       settings.scroll = 3; 
      
      var $navPrev  = $el.find('span.ca-nav-prev'),
       $navNext  = $el.find('span.ca-nav-next');
      
      // hide the items except the first 3
      $wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );
      
      // the items will have position absolute 
      // calculate the left of each item
      $items.each(function(i) {
       $(this).css({
        position : 'absolute',
        left  : i * cache.itemW + 'px'
       });
      });
      
      // click to open the item(s)
      $el.find('a.ca-more').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
       if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
       cache.isAnimating = true;
       $(this).hide();
       var $item = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
       aux.openItem( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
       return false;
      });
      
      // click to close the item(s)
      $el.find('a.ca-close').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
       if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
       cache.isAnimating = true;
       var $item = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
       aux.closeItems( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
       return false;
      });
      
      // navigate left
      $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
       if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
       cache.isAnimating = true;
       aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
      });
      
      // navigate right
      $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
       if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
       cache.isAnimating = true;
       aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
      });
      
      // adds events to the mouse
      $el.bind('mousewheel.contentcarousel', function(e, delta) {
       if(delta > 0) {
        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
        cache.isAnimating = true;
        aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
       } 
       else {
        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
        cache.isAnimating = true;
        aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
       } 
       return false;
      });
      
     });
    }
   }
  };
 
 $.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
  if ( methods[method] ) {
   return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
  } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
   return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
  } else {
   $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel' );
  }
 };
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* Circular Content Carousel Style */

/*Three points are very important when we want the image to fit the space required: by default: .ca-container{width:1205px;}, .ca-item{width:410px;}, .ca-item-main{width:380px;}  */
.ca-container{
 position:relative;
 margin:25px auto 20px auto;
 width:1205px;
 height:650px;
}
.ca-wrapper{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
.ca-item{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 width:410px;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
.ca-item-main{
 position:absolute;
 width: 380px;
 top:5px;
 left:5px;
 right:5px;
 bottom:5px;
 background:#fff;
 overflow:hidden;
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.ca-nav span{
 width:25px;
 height:38px;
 background:transparent url(../images/arrows.png) no-repeat top left;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 margin-top:-19px;
 left:-40px;
 text-indent:-9000px;
 opacity:0.7;
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:100;
}
.ca-nav span.ca-nav-next{
 background-position:top right;
 left:auto;
 right:-40px;
}
.ca-nav span:hover{
 opacity:1.0;
}

/*Text over image*/
h2.header {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 padding: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
 font-family: FeaturedItem;
}
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
   display: block;
   max-width:100%;
}

.wrapper .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:380px;
    height:100%;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Circular Content Carousel with jQuery</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
    <div class="ca-wrapper">
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/2.jpg"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/5.jpg"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/6.jpg"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/2.jpg"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/5.jpg"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/6.jpg"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-7">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/2.jpg"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-8">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/5.jpg"  alt="" />
        
        <div class="overlay">
         <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anybody need to run the code in local then a .zip file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0pgyk8mbplgih0/carousel.zip?dl=0

please let me know how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a minute and see how people ask questions here. They post CODE. Please post some relevant code.

Comment: Before asking a new question make sure you read [help] and [ask]

Comment: Ok thanks. Im new, I think I need to go around and see how the posts look like

Comment: This is a good example of a context where using 2 spaces, rather than tabs for indentation would really help people read and understand your code, at least on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really believe you couldn't post your code here. even I couldn't clone it on `jsfiddle` ! but rules are rules!

anyway, you can fix your issue with this:

```
    .ca-item-main {
        position: absolute;
        width: 405px;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper img {
        display: block;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

.ca-container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px auto 20px auto;
    width: 1230px;
    height: 650px;
}
```

Comment: Post updated...

Thanks for helping. What you did works but the third item is not fully shown.

Comment: I increased your `width` just this. post updated, also need to increase `.ca-container` width.

Comment: Thanks one more time.

I just noticed that the images are now 405px instead of 380px.
then I try to set the width of the class ca-item-main and ca-item to 380px, whenever I do that I come back to the initial display

Comment: I think it's only solution to fix this issue that increase width of ca-item. I didn't see any margin or padding for remove to fix that gap.